# Audio Encoder for Flash

Tags: flash, http, mp3, audio-recording, oggvorbis

Are there any audio encoding libraries for Flash? I need to record sound from a Flash applet, and then upload it to a server with HTTP.

The problem is that the raw audio file is really big. Is there any way to encode it into MP3/OGG/etc from Flash and *then* upload it to the server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably nothin for MP3/ogg. Older versions of flash include the nellymoser codec - but sue to licencing of this there are issues around decoding it. Since v.10, flash support the [speex](http://www.speex.org/) codec.